# How to create an Observable from a Deferred future using Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, observable, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to create an Observable using Futures with Coroutines.

Here is what I tried:

```
private fun getHelloObservable(): Observable<String>{
        val deferred = GlobalScope.async {
            "Hello"
        }

        return Observable.just(deferred.await())
    }
```

But I get the following error:

> Suspend function 'await' should be called only from a coroutine or
>   another suspend function.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty bad idea... coroutines won't help you at all in this, their purpose is to eliminate `Observable` and `Future` from your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `kotlinx-coroutines-rx2` to bridge to the reactive world:

```
rxSingle { deferred.await() }
```

And from there it's as easy as calling `toObservable()` to actually get an `Observable`.

Comment: `deferred.asSingle()`would even be simpler.